# Every subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is convergent.True/false

Tags: real-analysis

Is the  following statement is  true/false

Let $\{x _n\}_{n \ge 1}$ be  a  bounded  sequence  of real numbers . Then  every  subsequence  of  $\{x_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is convergent

I think  this  statement is true by the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem

But False ,if we  take $x_n= \sin n $ clearly $|x_n| \le 1$

and take subsequence $x_{2k}= \sin 2k$ and $x_{2k+1}=\sin {2k+1}$ is not convergent

Answer (score 2):

Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem states that every bounded sequence has a convergence subsquence.

It is an existential statement. It doesn't claim that every subsequence is convergent.